# Create multiple rows in table based on multi-select dropdown (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, drop-down-menu, dashboard, rhandsontable

I am building a Shiny app with 2 tabs.  The first tab contains 2 multi-select dropdown menus.  The 2nd tab contains a table that is filtered/impacted by the selections of the 2 dropdowns from the previous tab.  The first dropdown filters the table.

The second dropdown is a little different: I want the selections in the 2nd dropdown to all populate in their respective column in the table on the 2nd tab.  Further, I would like an additional row to be created for each additional selection beyond the 1st selection.  For example, if I had a dataset like the following:

```
Col1    Col2     Col3
1       a        Group1      
2       a        Group2
3       b        Group3
4       b        Group2
5       b        Group3
6       b        Group2
7       a        Group2
```

Let's say the first dropdown filters Col2 and I only want to see values = a.  Then, we have:

```
Col1    Col2     Col3
1       a        Group1      
2       a        Group2
7       a        Group2
```

Next, I want the 2nd dropdown to able to select any of Groups 1, 2, or 3 from Col3 regardless of what is left after the first filtering step.  So, if I select Group 1 and Group 3 from the dropdown on the previous tab - I want the # of rows to double.  So, it would essentially look like this:

```
Col1    Col2     Col3
1       a        Group1     
1       a        Group3     
2       a        Group1
2       a        Group3
7       a        Group1
7       a        Group3
```

Here is some example code I've started on:

```
#----- Load libraries -----#
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)

# Define UI for application 

ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title="Draft"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Filtering Questions",
                 tabName = "questions",
                 icon = icon('question')
        ),
        menuItem("All Data",
                 tabName = "all_data",
                 icon=icon("table")
        )
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "questions",
          selectInput(
            inputId = 'q1',
            label = '1.) Choose carb',
            choices = unique(mtcars$carb),
            selected = unique(mtcars$carb)[1],
            multiple = TRUE
          ),
          br(),
          selectInput(
            inputId = 'q2',
            label = '2.) Choose gear',
            choices = unique(mtcars$gear),
            selected = unique(mtcars$gear)[1],
            multiple = TRUE
        )),
        tabItem(
          tabName = "all_data",
          rHandsontableOutput("all_table")
        )
      ))))

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  mtcars_filter = reactive({
    filter = subset(mtcars,carb %in% input$q1)
    
    #Add in value(s) selected for gear --> will create 1, 2, or 3 possible rows per indicator
    
    return(filter)
  })
  
  #----------All Data Table----------#
  output$all_table=renderRHandsontable({
    
    
    my_table = rhandsontable(mtcars_filter()) %>%
      hot_col(c(1:11), readOnly = TRUE) %>%
      hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE) %>%
      hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE)
    
    return(my_table)
    
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How do I implement this logic to add rows based on the dropdown selections?  I'm not sure how to incorporate this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)

df <- read.table(text = 
"col1    col2     col3
1       a        Group1      
2       a        Group2
3       b        Group3
4       b        Group2
5       b        Group3
6       b        Group2
7       a        Group2", header=T)

# Define UI for application 

ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title="Draft"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
        menuItem("Filtering Questions",
                 tabName = "questions",
                 icon = icon('question')
        ),
        menuItem("All Data",
                 tabName = "all_data",
                 icon=icon("table")
        )
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "questions",
          selectInput(
            inputId = 'q1',
            label = '1.) Choose col2',
            choices = unique(df$col2),
            selected = unique(df$col2)[1],
            multiple = TRUE
          ),
          br(),
          selectInput(
            inputId = 'q2',
            label = '2.) Choose col3',
            choices = unique(df$col3),
            selected = unique(df$col3)[1],
            multiple = TRUE
          )),
        tabItem(
          tabName = "all_data",
          rHandsontableOutput("all_table")
        )
      ))))

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

  df_filter1 <- reactive(subset(df, col2 %in% input$q1) %>% select(-col3))
  
  my_filter <- reactive({
    df2 <- df_filter1() %>% merge(input$q2) 
    names(df2)[3] <- "col3"
    df2[order(df2$col1),]
  })

  #----------All Data Table----------#
  output$all_table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(my_filter())
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```